# Door lock cover on Toyota Highlander

Tags: toyota, part-identification, highlander

I have a 2010 Toyota Highlander that is missing the cover to the lock on the drivers door. Can anybody tell me the name of the part so I can find a replacement? The dealership wanted $50+ for parts and labor, while it's just a simple plastic piece that snaps on there.

[image]

Comment: So the dealership wouldn't sell you just the part?  Try a different dealer, because you're probably not going to find it aftermarket anyway.

Comment: He said there was a rubber gasket or something and wasn't very helpful after that. Was hoping to find in a junkyard or something. Just wasn't sure what it was called.

Comment: Heh, maybe you have more formal just yards, but I think "that chrome deal that covers up the key hole cover" would work!  Hopefully there's someone with access to the Toyota parts catalog that knows more.

Comment: I tried that with 2 different junk yards but have not heard back. I figured I needed to be more specific. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not get any junkyard to reply to my inquiry. I contacted the parts department directly at the dealership and they were able to order it at a reasonable price.